# Почему появляется неожиданное поведение у добавленного к прототипу строки метода?

Tags: javascript, prototype

У меня есть список токенов такого вида:

```
OPEN_TAG: {
    regex: /</gm,
    name: 'OPEN_TAG',
},
CLOSE_TAG: {
    regex: />/gm,
    name: 'CLOSE_TAG',
},
CLOSE_SLASH: {
    regex: /\//gm,
    name: 'CLOSE_SLASH',
},
NEW_LINE: {
    regex: /\n/gm,
    name: 'NEW_LINE',
},
ANY_WORD: {
    regex: /[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9\w]/gm,
    name: 'ANY_WORD',
}
```

Далее, я определили новый метод у прототипа строки, который возвращал бы мне тип символа:

```
String.prototype.get_type = function() {
for(let type in types.TOKENS) {
    if( types.TOKENS[type].regex.test(this) ) {
        return type
    }
}

return 'UNKNOWN_TOKEN'
}
```

При вызове метода подряд происходит абсолютно неожиданное поведение:

```
console.log('d'.get_type())
console.log('d'.get_type())
console.log('d'.get_type())
console.log('d'.get_type())
console.log('d'.get_type())
console.log('d'.get_type())
console.log('d'.get_type())
console.log('d'.get_type())

ANY_WORD
UNKNOWN_TOKEN
ANY_WORD     
UNKNOWN_TOKEN
ANY_WORD     
UNKNOWN_TOKEN
ANY_WORD     
UNKNOWN_TOKEN
```

Такой вывод я вижу в своей консоли. В чем причина такого чередования?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод test() выполняет поиск совпадения между регулярным выражением и указанной строкой. Возвращает true или false .

Объекты JavaScript RegExp сохраняют состояние , если для них установлены global или sticky флаги (например, /foo/g или /foo/y ). Они хранят lastIndex из предыдущего совпадения. Используя это внутренне, test() можно использовать для перебора нескольких совпадений в текстовой строке (с группами захвата).

Источник: https://runebook.dev/ru/docs/javascript/global_objects/regexp/test

То есть для того чтобы всё заработало так, как вы ожидаете, вам следует убрать флаг g из регулярных выражений.

Примеры:

```js
const regBug = /\d/g // поиск всех цифр
const reg = /\d/ // поиск первой цифры
console.log('/////////////Использование регулярного выражения без переменной')
console.log(/\d/g.test('9'))
console.log(/\d/g.test('9'))
console.log(/\d/g.test('9'))
/// переменная regBug из-за флага g "хранит в себе" индекс последнего найденного элемента и продолжает поиск с него
console.log('/////////////regBug с 1 символом')
console.log(regBug.test('9'))
console.log(regBug.test('9'))
console.log(regBug.test('9'))
console.log(regBug.test('9'))
console.log('/////////////regBug с несколькими символами')
console.log(regBug.test('9999'))
console.log(regBug.test('9999'))
console.log(regBug.test('9999'))
console.log(regBug.test('9999'))
console.log(regBug.test('9999'))
//// Т.к тут уже 4 символа false будет появляться через каждые 4 раза.
console.log('/////////////reg с 1 символом')
console.log(reg.test('9'))
console.log(reg.test('9'))
console.log(reg.test('9'))
console.log(reg.test('9'))
console.log(reg.test('9'))
console.log(reg.test('9'))
```